# How update/transform values from objects inside an array in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Given an array of objects, iterate over it and change/add a few props while keeping most of the original props intact.

in javascript it would look like:

```
const trips = [
    { status: 1, name: "trip1", foo: "bar" }, 
    { status: 1, name: "trip2", foo: "bar" }, 
    { status: 3, name: "trip3", foo: "foobar" }]

const formatedTrips = trips.map(trip => ({
    ...trip,
    status: 1,
    foo: trip.foo === "bar" ? ` ${trips.name} bar` : "barbar"
}))

/**
 *  formatedTrips = [
        { status: 1, name: "trip1", foo: "trip1 bar" }, 
        { status: 1, name: "trip2", foo: "trip2 bar" }, 
        { status: 1, name: "trip3", foo: "barbar" }
    ]
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

`dart` has all of the standard array methods such as `map`, `filter` (it's called `where`), `reduce` and so on.
They are very intuitive and feel very similar to JS.
[docs](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables)

More specifically, it depends on the type of `trip`. Is it a map? An instance of a custom class? If you'll share the inner workings of your code it'll be easier to help.

Comment: I've checked most of array method, but didn't find any that does this simple transformations.
trip is just an object that was mapped from a api response.
But I've updated the code to give more details about it'

Comment: Are you somewhat familiar with dart's type system? `dart` is a statically typed language with no concept of native key: value objects like JS objects. Instead, there are different types such as `Map<String, dynamic>` which are probably more suited to what you need. Something like `var a = {"wouldCompile": false}` just isn't valid `dart` code. Again - if you were to share some of the `dart` source code, it would be much easier to help.